# How to reliably extract UI information from video game stream?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to extract meaningful information from video streams of Super Smash Bros. for Wii U, a fighting game with a very sparse UI.

[Example screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2yqj.png)

From this I want to tell the number of players, their character names, and their current damage (the large percentage number). Everything I've tried so far has failed, because so few elements of the UI are static:

- [Some videos are within overlays and may be scaled and moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwJzS.png)
- Most matches contain 2 players, but may contain up to 8 players
- Character portraits often fade out to nearly transparent,
- Character names may be very short ('Ike') or very long ('Mr. Game & Watch'), so they overlap the edges of the triangle-shaped box they're in.
- The box behind the character name varies in color, commonly, but not always, red and blue (in 2-player matches)
- The game behind the UI is extremely noisy and may even be completely black or white at times.
- The large number text changes from white to a red gradient as the value increases.
- The large number text is completely absent when a player has been KOed.

I've tried the following things:

- Template matching. Even with (slow) multi-scale matching, the percent sign changes in position and color very often, requiring a low threshold for matching, in turn producing noisy results.
- Trying to find the character name by thresholding and finding horizontally-connected contours. This fails when the background is very bright. It also often matched undesirable elements on the stream overlay.
- Finding edges and contours to find the triangle-shaped background behind the player name. Again, it failed because the background is very noisy (often there is a red player with a red background with no discernible edge)
- Feature matching. There are hundreds of possible portraits, and the character-name-text (which is relatively static) is very small so there are few features available for matching.

I don't have any formal training in computer vision tasks, so I'm not sure how to progress. It seems like this should be a relatively straightforward task given the elements are 2d and never rotate or skew, but I know that's a dangerous assumption to make.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it. No language preference, but I have been using python.

Comment: do you have to extract those information from a single image or from video? you might be able to find "stable" parts like the name if you combine information of multiple frames.

Comment: is same level of life percentage always colored same and independent from background? you could use 100 templates (0-100%) and apply them with fixed scale and fixed position once found (e.g. ssd).